# System restore from NAS drive using system restore disk

Tags: windows-7, nas, system-restore

I have a Seagate Flexdrive, onto which I save my backup Windows 7 images. To test that system image restore worked, I tried a dummy run. When I booted system restore disk, it said that it could find the NAS drive. I'm assuming that its system restore disk does not load up network drivers. Anyone know what might be causing this or have a workaround?

Comment: Are you using wired or wireless NAS?

Comment: its a wired NAS.

Comment: Yes Windows RE loads wired network drivers for your nic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select "System Image Recovery" from the tools list in Windows RE, it will give and error "Windows cannot find a system image on this computer", click "cancel" then "Next" then "advanced" button, here you will be able to search for a network location or load a driver for your NAS if it is needed.

.

[image]

.

[image]

Comment: Doesnt work. Cant access NAS drive. I get the login to popup but known user/pass not working. Ive tried using IP and NAS hostname. Also, switched off windows managing of homegroup connections.

Comment: get windows error when i try to logon 0x800704cf. Ive googled it but cant find anything in relation to nas drives specifically or system restore from repair disc.

Comment: Ok figured it out. I had to load windows drivers from motherboard software disc. Restore is running now.

Comment: Glad you solved it, which drivers in particular?

Comment: just a set of LAN drivers for onboard NIC, that came with motherboard. I should have remembered, cause windows didnt have the drivers when I first set the machine up. doh.